# Add QGIS Server WMS layer to GeoExt template

Tags: wms, geoext, boundless-suite, qgis-server, sdk

How to add QGIS Server WMS layer to GeoExt template (OpenGeoSuite SDK)?
I used the following code, but unsuccessful display layer

```
    qgis: {
        ptype: "gxp_wmssource",
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi",
        title: "Local QGIS MapServer",
        version:"1.1.1"
    },  


    {
        source: "qgis",
        title: "QGIS Server Layer",
        map: "/home/hast/UA/qgis-mapnik.qgs",
        layers: "buildings",
        opacity: 1,
        group: "overlays"
     }
```

I didn't find any information about it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the OpenGeoSuiteSDK lately but I guess you could just use the GetMap-URL which will probably look like this: http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/hast/UA/qgis-mapnik.qgs

Have you tried the following yet?:

```
qgis: {
        ptype: "gxp_wmssource",
        url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?map=/home/hast/UA/qgis-mapnik.qgs",
        version:"1.1.1"
    },
```

//////////

```
    {
        source: "qgis",
        title: "QGIS Server Layer",
        name: "buildings",
        opacity: 1
     }
```

Edit1: Just gave it a try and it works for me ;)

I also added a proxy config, as my QGIS-Server deliveres the tiles on a different port:

```
var app = new gxp.Viewer({
    proxy: "proxy/?url=",
```

...........

and added the override for ExtJS

```
 * @require overrides/override-ext-ajax.js
```

[image]